# posting a JObject to an action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, json.net

I was reading Rick Strahls

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/May/08/Passing-multiple-POST-parameters-to-Web-API-Controller-Methods

I would like to be able to use JObject in to the the action. 
I wrote a controller like this

```
public class AlbumsController : Controller
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public string PostAlbum(JObject jsonData)
    {
        return "success";
    } 
}
```

the front end looks like this

when the ajax gets called I get an error

```
       $("#a").click(function () { 
            var album = {
                AlbumName: "PowerAge",
                Entered: "1/1/1977"
            }
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: "Albums/PostAlbum",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify({ Album: album }),
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result.Result);
                }
            });
        });
```

`POST http://localhost:50066/Albums/PostAlbum 500 (Internal Server Error)` jquery-1.7.1.js:8102
send jquery-1.7.1.js:8102
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery-1.7.1.js:7580
(anonymous function) albums:74
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.7.1.js:3256
elemData.handle.eventHandle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your controller should derive from [`ApiController`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.aspx), not from [`Controller`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.aspx):

```
public class AlbumsController : ApiController
```

Also if you are using the default route setup:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

I would recommend you to use RESTful action names:

```
public class AlbumsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post(JObject jsonData)
    {
        return "success";
    } 
}
```

and then:

```
$('#a').click(function () { 
    var album = {
        AlbumName: "PowerAge",
        Entered: "1/1/1977"
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/albums',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ Album: album }),
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```